# iOS openURL event listener?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

starting to learn iOS and swift programming.

Just realised that there are som changes regarding opening URL schemes and how you can open other apps in iOS9.
http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes

Basically to use [canOpenURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) you will have to add the URL schemes in the info.plist. That is not really a choice for my application.

So I just want to use [openURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:) and I know it will return true/false depending if the URL/app can be opened or not. But how do I know the user input since the first time openURL is fired a dialog will appear; asking the user if the app should be opened.

How do I know if the user choose "OK" or "Cancel"? Is there any eventlistener/completionHandler/delegate I can set up to monitor this?

Comment: If the user chooses "OK" your app will go into the background. That's about the only "notification" you will get besides the return value to `openURL:`.

Comment: hm... ok, then I wont know if the user is redirected back to my app again after he or she has performed the action needed in the app that was opened or if the user choose "Cancel". Well guess I have to take this into account then.

Comment: Huh? If the user chooses Cancel, your app doesn't go into the background.

Comment: Sry, misunderstood, you are correct, the app will enter background if user chooses OK, but not if the user chooses Cancel.